# Ember Save a change to an attribute

Tags: node.js, ember.js, ember-data, sails.js, ember-cli

Very new to Ember, quick question please: How do I save/persist a change to an attribute? Have the following action in the controller:

```
actions: {

    togOnField: function(){

        if (this.get('onField')){
            this.set('onField', false);
        } else {
            this.set('onField', true);
        }
    }

}
```

Looking around I've found

```
this.get('model').save
```

At the moment, using this, the attribute is immediately reverting back to its previous state. Does this mean the save is unsuccessful? Working with a Sails API and Postgres DB, both seem to be working fine.

And what are the different options for how I might save from this action? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` in that controller refers to the controller, probably not the model as you expect. One thing you can do is pass in the model to the action.

In your template,

```
<button {{action 'toggleOnField' user}}>Toggle on field</button>
```

Then the action becomes

```
actions: {
  toggleOnField: function(user) {
    user.toggleProperty('onField').save().then(function() {
      // do something
    }, function(reason) {
      // handle error
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this has cleaned up my code a lot already. But still won't save. So I guess its a problem with the backend, and its ability to receive the update/PUT requests...